# HTML5 'canvas' element's z-index

Tags: html, css, z-index

In HTML and CSS prior to HTML5 and CSS3, it was possible to position two elements on top of each other, with transparent backgrounds, and set one to receive 'mouseover' events by using the z-index property of that element.

I have been try to do this with a 'canvas' under a HTML5 block-level element, but the canvas seems to block events in the layer with the higher z-index.

Is this expected behaviour?

I am testing in the latest Mozilla.

Comment: Please provide a test via http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: Use SVG for this, not Canvas.

Comment: P.S. "the latest Mozilla" will lose context as soon as a newer one comes out.

Comment: Latest Mozilla is currently Firefox 14.